# Start Apache Mesos slave with Docker containerizer

Tags: mesos, apache-aurora

I have a setup with Mesos and Aurora, I have dockerized my application which I need to deploy, now i have to start mesos slave with the docker support, but I'm not able to start the mesos slave with docker support, I'm trying the following:

```
sudo service mesos-slave --containerizers=docker,mesos start
```

this gives me

```
mesos-slave: unrecognized service
```

but if I try :

```
sudo service mesos-slave start
```

the slave gets activated.

Can anyone let me know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also inform people about what OS you're using, otherwise it's mostly guesswork.

Normally, your `/etc/mesos-slave/containerizers` should contain the following to enable Docker support:

```
docker,mesos
```

Then, you'd have to restart the service:

```
sudo service mesos-slave restart
```

References:

- https://open.mesosphere.com/getting-started/install/#slave-setup
- https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html
- https://open.mesosphere.com/advanced-course/deploying-a-web-app-using-docker/

Comment: thanks, that solved the issue. I didn't exactly know where to add docker.